# HttpServletRequest.getServerName() occasionally returning null in concurrent use?

Tags: java, concurrency, jboss, web-services, servlets

Under JBoss 4.0.1SP1, I have a servlet that makes multiple, concurrent calls to web services that are running under the same instance. I'm using request.getServerName() (on HttpServletRequest) to construct the endpoint URL. This normally works fine, but every once in a while returns null.

I hadn't seen this before running the web service requests in parallel, and so I guessed that sharing the HttpServletRequest among threads won't always work or something.

Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: Good lord, 4.0.1SP1? That release was *astonishingly* buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas on fixing this?

Upgrade JBoss.

Comment: Another option is to retrieve/externally-configure/hardcode it once and store/use it as applicationwide variable.

Comment: We'll be upgrading the version of JBoss soon.

I also tried calling request.getServerName() until I get non-null back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm probably missing something obvious, but .... if they're all on the same instance/server, then why do you need to pull the server name programmatically - why not just have it in a config file?

Comment: I want to pull the name programmatically so that it's easier to expand in the future & so that I don't have another thing to configure.