# How do I fix squid:S2259 `NullPointerException might be thrown as 'getString' is nullable here`?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code block

```
/**
 * Checks if the server name is equal to localhost in the servlet request.
 *
 * @param request
 *            servlet request
 * @return true if the server name is equal to localhost.
 */
public boolean isLocalHost(@Nonnull final ServletRequest request) {

    return settings != null && settings.getString(LOCALHOST) != null && settings.getString(LOCALHOST).equals(request.getServerName());
}
```

But Sonarqube keeps on complaing that `getString` may be nullable, even though from what I can tell it can't happen due to boolean short circuiting

Comment: Assign return value from `getString()` to a variable? Side benefit: You only call it once, i.e. better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarQube cannot recognize the fact that successive calls of `settings.getString` will return the same value.

Might be it is right because it possible if other thread modify settings between calls.

So assigning value to variable as @Andreas mentioned in comment should resolve this issue.

**UPD**:

```
 public boolean isLocalHost(@Nonnull final ServletRequest request) {
     if(settings == null) {
         return false;
     }

     String localhost = settings.getString(LOCALHOST);

     return localhost != null && localhost.equals(request.getServerName());
 }
```

Or check variable from another side:

```
 public boolean isLocalHost(@Nonnull final ServletRequest request) {
    String requestServerName = request.getServerName();

    return settings != null && requestServerName != null && requestServerName.equals(settings.getString(LOCALHOST));
 }
```

**UPD2**: Removed one of snippets because [HttpServletRequest.getServerName() occasionally returning null in concurrent use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426863/httpservletrequest-getservername-occasionally-returning-null-in-concurrent-use)

Comment: just add the appropriate code sample then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Just to add one thing :  two successive calls might return different results even if there is no multithreading involved `int foo() { return i++;}`